# YouTube Api PHP playlist of all videos for a channel

Tags: php, api, youtube

Hello I have some YouTube channels I watch regularly and I want to build a website in PHP which will show me which channels have uploaded a new video recently.

I want to get a list of all the videos for a YouTube channel ordered by date. Preferably all videos the owner has uploaded to his channel. I'm not concerned what playlist they are in.

I am using the Google client api library and have got as far as this which works:

```
include_once '/youtube/google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);

$client->setApplicationName("App");
$client->setDeveloperKey("abc123");

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
```

I know it works because this search query returns search results:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => 'cars',
  'maxResults' => 10,
));
```

However can someone point me in the correct direction for which API call to use to get a list of videos from a channel I specify?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the Google api explorer https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list

Worked out what I needed to do was this:

```
$videos = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('id,snippet,contentDetails', array(
      'playlistId' => 'abc123',
      maxResults => 50
    ));
```

To get the 'uploads' playlist id where all the videos are kept for a channel do a youtube.channels.list api call with part = contentDetails and id = their channel id